# response object is not defined in some scenarios

Tags: javascript, ajax, frontend, yui

I am fixing a bug in this code. In some scenarios `responseObj` is null and says that

> responseObj is not defined

Backend of this application is written in perl. Can anyone give a solution or any suggestion?

```js
function handleGiveUp(part) {
  if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to request the answer to this question? If you do, you will not get any credit for it.")) {
    return;
  }

  var ioArgs = {
    action: 'showAnswer',
    assignmentProblemID: part.parent.config.assignmentProblemID,
    partID: part.id,
    noErrorAlertOnSuccess: true,
    aCSRFToken: MxData.aCSRFToken
  };

  shieldedSubmitServerCall(part, ioArgs, {
    onSuccess: function(responseObj) {
      processShowAnswer(part, responseObj.data);
    }
    function handleGiveUp(part) {
      if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to request the answer to this question? If you do, you will not get any credit for it.")) {
        return;
      }

      var ioArgs = {
        action: 'showAnswer',
        assignmentProblemID: part.parent.config.assignmentProblemID,
        partID: part.id,
        noErrorAlertOnSuccess: true,
        aCSRFToken: MxData.aCSRFToken
      };

      shieldedSubmitServerCall(part, ioArgs, {
        onSuccess: function(responseObj) {
          processShowAnswer(part, responseObj.data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged perl?

Comment: The related action for this is              action: 'showAnswer', it calls a perl action file

Comment: @P.N.Jayasinghe but you didn't include any perl code, tags should be related to your issue. You can add condition and execute `processShowAnswer` only if `responseObj` is not null and has property data (or call it with null) or you can fix your backend